# Molar conductivities of aqueous electrolytes at 1 M

Tags: reference-request, conductivity

In the following [table from the CRC Handbook](http://hbcponline.com/faces/documents/05_08/05_08_0001.xhtml), molar conductivities of aqueous electrolytes are given for concentrations from infinite dilution to 0.1 M.  However, I am looking for values at 1 M, and I'm having a hard time finding that information.  (The following table probably stops at 0.1 M because the Debye-Huckel-Onsager equation is only accurate for very dilute solutions.)

This is a soft question, I admit, but can anyone suggest resources for finding tables of molar conductivities of aqueous electrolytes (i.e., typical ones like $KCl$, $KOH$, $H_2SO_4$) at **1 M**?

[image: molar]

Comment: Go to Google Scholar and search the title "Transport in Concentrated Solutions of 1:1 Electrolytes".